# What's a good way to handle entities within an aggregate that persist to multiple databases

Tags: database, domain-driven-design, repository, unit-of-work

I'm dealing with a design problem that I'm sure has a simple answer and/or has been solved before. I've been reading, thinking, and searching for solutions for quite a while, but nothing seems to really make sense.

The gist of the issue is that I'm dealing with a series of legacy systems and databases and I'm trying to take a DDD approach to building new apps and replacing older ones. The core issue is that while my domain entities, value objects, and aggregates make business sense, when I consider persistence I have one big problem... the entities within an aggregate are currently persisted in multiple databases.

For example, let's say I have entities A, B, and C where A is the aggregate root. I have a repository for A and I'm employing the Unit Of Work around an NHibernate session for persistence. All is great and fine as long as A, B, and C are all persisted to a single server/database. In my case, however, A and B might be on one server/database and C might be persisted on a completely different server/database.

I realize that conventional wisdom might suggest that one should never do this, but I'm dealing with a legacy. Sure, in time I'll likely refactor the data tier to something more logical, but for now I'm stuck. I suspect that I'll always have this problem to some degree and I can't help but to think that others have crossed this bridge.

In short, I have a homegrown framework in C# consisting of Fluent/NHibernate for persistence, Unity for IoC and employing standard (or at least recognizable) Repository and Unit Of Work patterns. As for databases, I'm dealing with MS SQL Server and Oracle.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you get a little more specific?  Perhaps elaborate on A, B, and C?

Comment: So let's assume I've got an aggregate root that is Car with an Engine entity and a Wheel entity. I have a CarRepository and my Car and Wheel are persisted in Database ABC and my Engine is persisted in Database XYZ. Is there a way to use NHibernate (or similar) to persist it all (realizing that there would be more than one ISession)? Do I compromise my business domain and create EngineRepository and not expose Engine via CarRepository? I can't seem to come up with anything that doesn't wreak of design smells. Maybe try to build my own UoW that allows for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate root shouldn't live across multiple databases.

Greg Young talks about this same issue [here](http://domaindrivendesign.org/library/young_2010).

---

Something [like this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/08/20/application-databases-and-external-integration-points.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+AyendeRahien+(Ayende+%40+Rahien)&utm_content=Netvibes) is what You should be doing.

Comment: Agreed. I would never design from the ground-up like this, but it's inherited. For now, the only real solution I can come up with is to compromise my domain model and create repositories that center on a single database (or at least server).

Comment: @Greg check that link i provided. It might help You.

Comment: that link to Ayende's post was very helpful. I had to really sit and reconsider my approach, but in the end came out with a much better approach. Thanks!